# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "lure"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

El inglés tiene muchas palabras que, en una única sílaba, recogen muchísimos matices.

Una de las que más me ha llamado siempre la atención en este aspecto es "lure". Según yo la entiendo, significa algo así como tender una trampa a alguien para capturarlo o dirigirlo hacia donde tú quieres. Para mí, es una palabra que transmite intencionalidad, premeditación, intensidad y a veces cierta maldad o alevosía.

El [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lure) cita algunos ejemplos magníficos:

> - They lured the bear out of its den.
> - The suburbs are luring middle-class families away from the city.
> - The police lured him back to the scene of the crime.
> - Explorers were lured to the area by tales of a city of gold.
> - An attractive window display can help to lure shoppers into the
>     store.

Y [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=lure) da como traducciones las siguientes opciones: **lanzar el anzuelo**, **atraer**, **tentar**.

Sin embargo, para mí, se pierden muchos matices con estas opciones (como decía antes, intencionalidad, premeditación, intensidad, maldad). Así pues, mi pregunta, ¿cómo traduciríais este término de manera general, de forma que quede lo más idiomático posible, pero sin tener que utilizar una frase enorme?

Comment: Pienso que *tentar* es mejor para la otras por qué el signoficado de "to lure" es más cercano para "to tempt".

Comment: Vale, en el caso de los exploradores no es una trampa en sí, pero las leyendas (_tales_) es algo muy incierto y una imagen muy poderosa. No es una causa razonable y justificada, digamos.

Comment: En general yo diría *seducir*.  Pero si en el contexto podría darse un malentendido por el aspecto sexual, entonces no, habría que buscar otra cosa, por ejemplo *incitar*.  Pero sí, en general, yo diría *seducir*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El verbo *to lure* viene del mundo de la caza y pesca, y significa literalmente "atraer mediante un cebo". Es uno de esos típicos verbos ingleses basados en un sustantivo, en este caso *lure*: cebo.

Manteniendo esta connotación de "cebo", veo dos posibilidades:

> **[entruchar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=entruchar)**.
>
> 1. tr. coloq. Atraer a alguien con disimulo y engaño, para meterlo en un negocio.
>
> **[pescar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=pescar)**.
>
> 6. tr. coloq. Lograr o conseguir astutamente lo que se pretendía o anhelaba.

Aunque debo decir que "**atraer**" me parece totalmente válido, teniendo en cuenta (como he apuntado en un comentario) que la situación de "trampa final" no tiene por qué darse. De hecho, la connotación indicada por el MW es "con placer o ganancia", que *per se* no implica perjuicio para el atraído o la atraída.

Answer (score 2):

Otras posibilidades incluidas en el DRAE serían

**[Instigar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ln53CtO).**

> Inducir a alguien a una acción, generalmente considerada como negativa.

**[Inducir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LRVtrWa).**

> Mover a alguien a algo o darle motivo para ello.

(del DRAE)

Answer (score 2):

> Según yo la entiendo, significa algo así como tender una trampa a alguien para capturarlo o dirigirlo hacia donde tú quieres.

Bueno, en el idioma español tenemos:

> **[entrampar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FjlNN79)**
>
> 1. tr. Hacer que un animal caiga en la trampa. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. Engañar artificiosamente.

Aunque la verdad es que no suelo ver ese verbo muy usado, prevaleciendo en su lugar "tender una trampa" o "tender una emboscada". Hoy día "entramparse" se suele usar en su acepción sinónima de "endeudarse", al menos en España.

Otra opción que tampoco mantiene el significado original:

> **[raposear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V9UAoYV)**
>
> 1. intr. Emplear ardides o trampas.

En todo caso, yo diría que en los ejemplos que has puesto encaja perfectamente el verbo ***atraer***:

- Atrajeron al oso afuera de su cueva.
- El extrarradio está atrayendo a las familias de clase media.
- El policía le atrajo de vuelta a la escena del crimen.
- A los exploradores les atraían las historias de la ciudad dorada.
- Un escaparate vistoso ayuda a atraer a los compradores.

Con estos ejemplos no considero que *lure* implique necesariamente una trampa, sino solo una atracción. Y lo que comentas de que *lure* implica "intencionalidad, premeditación, intensidad y a veces cierta maldad o alevosía" lo respeta *atraer*.

Answer (score 2):

Como dice @Charlie, en los ejemplos que has puesto lo que mejor encaja es *atraer* sin duda.

Dicho esto si queremos darle el sentido de trampa, cebo o señuelo hay varias palabras que tienen ese significado de atraer con engaños:

> **[embaucar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ec86tAA)**
>
> 1. tr. Engañar o alucinar, prevaliéndose de la inexperiencia o candor del engañado.

Con un matiz un poco distinto tenemos también:

> **[engatusar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FMaToZa)**
>
> 1. tr. coloq. Ganar la voluntad de alguien con halagos para conseguir de él algo.

Y una palabra curiosa que descubrí buscando sinónimos de las anteriores:

> **[engaitar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FKJEJb6)**
>
> 1. tr. coloq. Engañar con promesas y con palabras artificiosas y deslumbradoras.

También habría otras similares como camelar, encandilar, etc.