# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "engatusar"?

Tags: significado, historia

Como se puede ver en esta [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23002/c%C3%B3mo-se-puede-traducir-lure/23124#23124), *engatusar* significa:

> "Ganar la voluntad de alguien con halagos para conseguir de él algo".

Se me viene a la idea un gato jugando con su presa ratón pero no me cuadra porque allí no se está empleando ningún engaño, ya para ese momento es demasiado tarde.

Comment: Quizás es porque el gato trata de encariñarse cuando quiere que le dés de comer.

Answer (score 4):

Pues no vas desencaminado. Según el DLE, la palabra *[engatusar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FMaToZa)* viene de *[engatar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FMOYtCw)*, con el mismo significado de "engañar halagando", y esta de *en-* y *gato*.

Dice Covarrubias en su diccionario de 1611:

> ENGATAR, vale comunmente engañar, tomada la comparacion del gato, quando quiere asir al raton.

La voz *engatusar* aparece registrada en 1732 en el *Autoridades*, por lo que es un poco más tardía que *engatar*, registrada según Corominas en 1601. Corominas también afirma que la voz pudo surgir confundida con el antiguo *[encatusar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=F2j2OJw)*, derivado de *encantar* ("engañar con brujerías", registrada en 1534), la propia voz *engatar*, y *[engaratusar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FLOFFSG)* ("engañar con halagos", derivada de *[garatusa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IsamF6g)* "carantoña", registrada en 1509). Finaliza diciendo que resulta pues de "*engaratusar* bajo el influjo de *engatar*".

Comment: [Etimologias de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?engatusar) dice que es una confluencia de dos voces: `encantusar` -un derivado de encantar (hechizar)-  y `engatar`